# Loop through all product posts?

Tags: posts, wp-query, loop

I want to loop through all my posts who are called 'products'.
For that I use this one:

```
$products_IDs = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => 'product'
    ));

while ($products_IDs->have_posts() ) : $products_IDs->the_post();
        $y = $y + 1; 
        $myfile = fopen("wp_all_import.txt", "a");
        fwrite($myfile, "Counter: " . $y . "\t");
        fclose($myfile);

        //some code...

        $sql = "INSERT INTO `wp_all_import` (pid, price, price_old, link, shop) VALUES ('$pid', '$price', '$price_old', '$link', '$shop')";
        if($database->query($sql) === TRUE){
            $myfile = fopen("wp_all_import.txt", "a");
            fwrite($myfile, "Inserted: " . $pid . " \n");
            fclose($myfile);
        }
```

But I always get only 10 loops nevertheless I have more then 10 product pages... More over 100... But the loop always is stopping at 10... look
https://gamekeys-shop.de/wp-admin/wp_all_import.txt

I don't know why... But how can I fix that or how can I find out why the loop is always stopping at 10?

Greetings and Thank You!

Comment: Set `WP_Query` parameter `posts_per_page` to `-1`.

Comment: What does that mean and how do I do that? - And where?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at WordPress codex for [`WP_Query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) for more information.

You'll see there are different parameters for `WP_Query`, you just need to add the [`posts_per_page`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#pagination-parameters) parameter with the value set to `-1` to show all posts.

```
$products_IDs = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
    ));

while ($products_IDs->have_posts() ) : $products_IDs->the_post();
    // Your code
endwhile;
```

Comment: I will test it tomorrow. So it is set to 10 without any parameter? - Does -1 also works if I only want all sites who are existing now? - I do not want allllll sites. Only those product pages who are existing right now!

Comment: And what does that mean? - "number of post to show per page"? I'm a German native speaker. I don't understand this term. Isn't post and page the same?

Comment: To simple it, I will explain it as : `posts_per_page` is like how many posts the `$products_ID->have_posts()` can contain.

For example, if you set it to **10**, you'll get **10** posts on `yoursite.com/` then you must go to `yoursite.com/page/2` to get the **10** next posts. It's a **pagination system**, not a **page** `post_type`.